# React spring transition, achieve a progressive delay in the entry of each element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, react-spring

The first example shown on the react-spring transition page is wrong, the code does not correspond to the animation shown.

How could I achieve that same effect?, how can I get a delay between the input of each component and using spring easing?.

When I try this, all components are entered at the same time.

[Use transition example](https://www.react-spring.io/docs/hooks/use-transition)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These examples in the documentation are just drafts to give you some overview. It is a shame that react-spring only provides more advanced animations and lacks some basic example.

Anyway. The most basic delay between elements can be achieved with the trail property of the transition.

```
  const transitions = useTransition(items, item => item, {
    from: { transform: "translate3d(0,-40px,0)", display: "inline-block" },
    enter: { transform: "translate3d(0,0px,0)" },
    leave: { transform: "translate3d(0,-40px,0)" },
    trail: 100
  });
```

You can use this parameter only for sequential delay. When more than one item added or removed from the array your transition based on.

https://codesandbox.io/s/new-bird-sztw9

In the first example they do not use this. They are supposed to add and remove the item to the list a little staggered. I try to reproduce it. This is the staggered add:

```
  function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  }

  const handleClick = async () => {
    if (items.length === 0) {
      set([3]);
      await sleep(1000);
      set([2, 3]);
      await sleep(1000);
      set([2, 3, 4]);
      await sleep(1000);
      set([1, 2, 3, 4]);
    } ...
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-sky-56lrw

This is closer to the example. But there are slight bumps when the mounts/unmounts of the transitions happen.

I hope it helps.

As a side note. I checked the source code of the react-spring page and they are cheating. The first example is do not even use transitions for the smooth animation. It uses interpolate to orchestrate the movement of each number. This is some advanced use with special components.

```
      <RewindSpring>
        {x => (
          <>
            <animated.div
              style={{
                opacity: x.interpolate({range: [0.75, 1.0], output: [0, 1]}),
                transform: x.interpolate({range: [0.75, 1.0], output: [-40, 0], extrapolate: 'clamp'}).interpolate(x => `translate3d(0,${x}px,0)`)
              }}
            >
              1
            </animated.div>
            <animated.div
              style={{
                opacity: x.interpolate({range: [0.25, 0.5], output: [0, 1]}),
                transform: x.interpolate({range: [0.25, 0.5], output: [-40, 0], extrapolate: 'clamp'}).interpolate(x => `translate3d(0,${x}px,0)`)
              }}
            >
              2
            </animated.div>
            <animated.div
              style={{
                opacity: x.interpolate({range: [0.0, 0.25], output: [0, 1]}),
                transform: x.interpolate({range: [0.0, 0.25], output: [-40, 0], extrapolate: 'clamp'}).interpolate(x => `translate3d(0,${x}px,0)`)
              }}
            >
              3
            </animated.div>
            <animated.div
              style={{
                opacity: x.interpolate({range: [0.5, 0.75], output: [0, 1]}),
                transform: x.interpolate({range: [0.5, 0.75], output: [-40, 0], extrapolate: 'clamp'}).interpolate(x => `translate3d(0,${x}px,0)`)
              }}
            >
              4
            </animated.div>
          </>
        )}
      </RewindSpring>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Peter for taking all this work, incredible response. It has been a great help to me, I also regret that react-spring does not have a better documentation for begginers, I find it difficult to understand its use whitout simple examples, even though I have a lot of experience in Javascirpt/React.